# Trouble with FluidMoveBehavior and Navigation (WP 8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox

I setup fluidmovebehavior to Listbox:

```
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <ilayout:FluidMoveBehavior AppliesTo="Children" Duration="0:0:0.3">
                            <ilayout:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
                                <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                            </ilayout:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
                        </ilayout:FluidMoveBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Listbox placed on MainPage.xaml and have some List as ItemsSource. Animation work fine, but when I navigate to new page (no matter what page, even blank page) I get System.ArgumentException. Then I commented all xaml code **ItemsPanelTemplate** , that is Fluid animation off. Then navigation work fine.

StackTrace:

```
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(System.IntPtr ptr, string name, MS.Internal.CValue[] cvData)
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodPack(System.IntPtr objectPtr, string methodName, object[] rawData)
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_TransformToVisual(System.Windows.UIElement element, System.Windows.UIElement visual)
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.TransformToVisual(System.Windows.UIElement visual)
microsoft.expression.interactions.DLL!Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Layout.FluidMoveBehaviorBase.TranslateRect(System.Windows.Rect rect, System.Windows.FrameworkElement from, System.Windows.FrameworkElement to)
microsoft.expression.interactions.DLL!Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Layout.FluidMoveBehaviorBase.UpdateLayoutTransition(System.Windows.FrameworkElement child)
microsoft.expression.interactions.DLL!Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Layout.FluidMoveBehaviorBase.AssociatedObject_LayoutUpdated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnLayoutUpdated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.JoltHelper.RaiseEvent(System.IntPtr target, uint eventId, System.IntPtr coreEventArgs, uint eventArgsTypeIndex)
```

**ADD:** If I set to listbox.ItemsSource = null , before navigation to another page, exception not happened.

What I am doing wrong?

Sorry for my bad lang) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one acceptable solution.

- Detach behavior before navigation on next page
- Attach behavior after navigation from some page to previous page(if use GoBack() method navigation)

  ```
  private void ChangeBehaviorState<T>(DependencyObject owner, BehaviorState state) where T : DependencyObject
  {
      DependencyObject root = UIHelper.FindChildOfType<T>(owner);
      if (root == null) return;            
      FluidMoveBehavior b = Interaction.GetBehaviors(root)[0] as FluidMoveBehavior;
      if (b == null) return;
      switch (state)
      {
          case BehaviorState.Attach:
              b.Attach(root);
              break;
          case BehaviorState.Detach:
              b.Detach();
              break;
      }
  }
  ```
- **BehaviorState,UIHelper** - custom classes for support.
- **root** - it is some class ListBox or another UIElement who have
  behavior.